# Single Domain Controller FSMO holder DR

Tags: domain, domain-controller, disaster-recovery, fsmo

We are looking at the topic of DR at the moment and I would like your expert help in the creation of a DR plan in the event that our PDC somehow goes kaput!

Info:
Our PDC holds all FSMO roles
We have 3 secondary DC's around our environment

Is there a method to transfer FSMO roles to another DC if we cannot access the PDC?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no immediate impact if your PDC DC goes down. You can plan to manually seize the PDC role from one of the remaining domain controllers. The process is descrbed well here https://www.petri.com/seizing_fsmo_roles

Comment: Many many thanks, this will be a great starting point to look at.

Comment: Would it be easier/quicker to restore the DC from a VM backup (perhaps 3 days old at the time)

Comment: Your concern with that approach should be replication issues. 3 days should be Ok but longer periods of time risk USN rollback. I don't have any direct experience recovering from a snapshot. https://windorks.wordpress.com/2014/07/25/ad-replication-issues-usn-rollback-and-the-invocation-id/

Answer (score 0):

You can't transfer, but you can seize them:

Seize the Operations Master Role
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816779%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: Many Thanks, Would it be easier/quicker to restore the DC from a VM backup (perhaps 3 days old at the time)